# Which code can I use in RStudio to create a new data frame that only contains duplicated values form another already created?

Tags: r

So I´m working in RStudio with this data set with more than 3 million observations, but right now I´m only intrested in kwning the specifics about duplicated observations, so I would like to know if ther´s any code I can use to creat a new data frame only with duplecated obs from a a certain variable?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could look into `?duplicated`...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll get a better response if you provide [a reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including example data in a plain text format (a small sample of the dataset with a few duplicates), and any code that you've used to try and solve the problem.